# ruby/irb get scope info for method

Tags: ruby, reflection

Can IRB tell me the scope of a class/object/variable/method?

For instance `puts`.

I am imagining something like `describe puts` would output information that puts is a method of object and perhaps where its source is located.

Comment: [`pry`](https://github.com/pry/pry) an `irb` alternative also has excellent methods for this like `show-method` which will output the file location and the method body

Comment: @engineersmnky still for methods written in ruby itself only :)

Comment: @mudasobwa please explain?

Comment: It won’t work for the core methods, written in C.

Comment: @mudasobwa not true `show-method puts` outputs "From: io.c (C Method):
Owner: Kernel
Visibility: private
Number of lines: 8

static VALUE
rb_f_puts(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE recv)
{
    if (recv == rb_stdout) {
        return rb_io_puts(argc, argv, recv);
    }
    return rb_funcall2(rb_stdout, rb_intern("puts"), argc, argv);
}"

Comment: Oh, indeed. Sorry, I was plain wrong, my understanding was obsolete. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by the "scope of an object", for example? Objects don't *have* scopes. The closest an object has to a scope is the *lifetime* of the object, and no, IRb cannot tell you the lifetime of the object, because statically determining the lifetime of an object is equivalent to solving the Halting Problem. (Put another way: if IRb could tell you the lifetime of an object, then Ruby wouldn't need garbage collection. The whole reason why garbage collection, reference counting, manual memory management etc. exist is because this cannot be done.)

Comment: Likewise, for methods, class, and variables, it is unclear what exactly you mean by "the scope of". Methods and classes *are* scopes (or rather their bodies are) but there are other scopes as well, and variables *belong* to scopes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the methods defined on `Kernel` / `Object` one might simply use:

```
method :puts
#⇒ #<Method: Object(Kernel)#puts>
```

For the method defined on the module/class that is not included everywhere, the fully qualified name is required:

```
Integer.instance_method :to_s
#⇒ #<UnboundMethod: Integer#to_s>
```

For methods, defined in ruby (not in [c](/questions/tagged/c),) the source location might be also queried:

```
URI.method(:split).source_location
#⇒ ["/path_to_ruby/uri/common.rb", 192]
```

Comment: And once you have the method, you can call `method.owner` to get the class. In this case, `method.owner` would return `Kernel`.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks for the URI tip. I see that I can get a Method object using this strategy. One question: I don't see URI#method method documented.

Can you explain how it works?

And can I also do this for class/instance?

Comment: It is a method of Object, or Module, or even Kernel. Use this technique to discover it with `URI.method(:method)` :)